# Перерисовка элемента

Tags: c#, uwp

Существует проблема обновления элемента на панели типа `VariableSizedWrapGrid`. При добавлении на панель кнопки методом `Childer.Add()`, кнопка тут же появляется, так же как и удаление этого элемента. Но вот при изменении каких то составляющих кнопки, изменения вступают в силу только при переходе на эту страницу с другой. Пробовал использовать метод `InvalidateMeasure()` для панели, но к результату не привело.

Comment: VM, которая является контекстом этой кнопки реализует INPC?

Comment: @АндрейNOP нет, я использовал имя панели, и передавал её в VM с помощью конструктора. Как можно привязать её с помощью x:Bind к ViewModel в таком случае? К какому свойству обратиться?

Comment: Имя из View вы передали в VM? Я не понимаю вас. У вас коллекция кнопок? Создавайте ее с помощью ItemsControl

Comment: @АндрейNOP я создал панель внутри фрейма, а её имя (x:Name) передал в code behind по ViewModel через параметры конструктора. А во ViewModel с помощью panel.Children.Add() добавляю кнопки, создаваемые программно. Т.е. они генерируются из базы.

Comment: Code behind и View Model это не одно и то же, VM ничего не должна знать о контролах и панелях. VM должна просто иметь коллекцию ваших элементов, а View должна с помощью привязки визуализовать эти элементы в виде кнопок или чего вы там хотите. Для этого заведите в VM ObservableCollection, а в View ItemsControl

Comment: @АндрейNOP Да, в Code behind я создаю объект ViewModel, а работа происходит в отдельном VM файле. В общем я добавил внутрь VariableSizedWrapGrid ItemsControl, свойство Sourse которого я привязал к коллекции кнопок. Все заработало, и изменения теперь применяются сразу, только возникла одна проблема. Кнопки теперь располагаются на панели вертикально, хотя должны горизонтально. Не подскажете, в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: @АндрейNOP проблема решена, VariableSizedWrapGrid добавлен в ItemsControl.ItemsPanel, все заработало как надо. Ваш совет использовать ItemsControl - то что нужно. Спасибо вам большое!

Comment: Пожалуйста, рад помочь! Если вы пишете что-то типа Children.Add или как-то по другому создаете контролы вручную, то скорее всего действуете неправильно и это можно сделать через шаблоны и привязку. ItemPanelTemplate, ItemTemplate и т.д